# How to read CSV file from POST?

Tags: csv, python-3.4, filefield, django-1.7

I've been stuck for hours on this csv problem. The following code is run after a form is posted :

```
fichier_en_lecture = request.FILES['fichier_csv'].read()
nom_du_fichier = request.FILES['fichier_csv'].name
importateur = request.user
traitement_du_fichier(fichier_en_lecture, importateur)
```

And the "traitement_du_fichier" function goes like this :

```
def traitement_du_fichier(fichier_en_lecture, nom_du_fichier, importateur):
    nouveau_fichier = FichierAdhérents(importateur=importateur, fichier_csv=nom_du_fichier)
    nouveau_fichier.save()
    import csv
    lecteur = csv.reader(fichier_en_lecture, delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
    for row in lecteur:
        nouvel_adhérent = AdhérentDuFichier()
        nouvel_adhérent['fichier_adhérents'] = nouveau_fichier
        column_counter = 0
        nouvel_adhérent['fédération'] = row[column_counter]
        column_counter += 1
        nouvel_adhérent['date_première_adhésion'] = row[column_counter]
        column_counter += 1
        nouvel_adhérent['date_dernière_cotisation'] = row[column_counter]
```

I get the following error :

```
iterator should return strings, not int (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

I've tried to use open() but from what I understand, open() only works with a direct path to the uploaded file. However, I need to do this from memory.

Answer (score 6):

In python 3,
I used:

```
import csv
from io import StringIO
csvf = StringIO(xls_file.read().decode())
reader = csv.reader(csvf, delimiter=',')
```

xls_file being the file got from the POST form.
I hope it helps.